# Custom IntelliSense system

Tags: intellisense

For a personal project I am looking forward to building a custom IntelliSense system, the project in question is a simple code editor.

What i had some problems with is the IntelliSense aspect of the editor, and in specifics, the highlighting of the code. How does the system know which words are keywords?

A solution is adding them manually, but wouldnt that mean that for third party libraries, it wont work since the program doesnt have the functions from that library or API?

So in short, how is the IntelliSense code highlighting logic constructed, and is there an archive of some type on internet where i can get a language's keywords? Keep in mind that i want to build this code editor as a multi-language one (supports many languages).

Comment: All the editors I've ever used seem to handle syntax highlighting and code intellisense in completely different modules. Are  you interested only in the former?

Comment: Well what's the difference actually? Yes i'm mainly interested in the syntax highlighting at the moment, but later on i will need to make also autocomplete since thats part of the IntelliSense

Comment: I don't really know why (I'm just a user). Perhaps it's for reusability and performance reasons. Syntax highlighting is relatively simple task that can be done with a simple tokenizer or even a regexp engine. Static analysis is an entirely different beast. If you're anyway interested in the latter you may want to check [Language Server Protocol](https://langserver.org/) by Microsoft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building decent support for even one non-trivial language is a lot of work. Consider using a library that will do it for you. Most of these will not be free, but are probably the way to go, unless the point of this exercise is you learning compiler theory.

An example of such a library is Microsoft's C# compiler (Roslyn). It's available as a free open source library that you can use in other .NET applications. You give it some code as input (as a string), and it tells you everything there is to know about that piece of code: where symbols and keywords are, what each symbol is, what to offer for autocomplete at which point, where compile-time errors in the code are, etc...

If you want to learn how to build something like this yourself, I suggest getting a compiler theory book and setting aside a few months. While it's not rocket science, it's not trivial either.

Once you have a basic grasp of lexers and parsers, then you'll probably want to use a parser/lexer generator like Antlr to do the tedious work of building a lexer and parser. After that, you still have a lot of work to process the syntax tree that the parser gives you. If you're building autocomplete (intellisense) keep in mind that while the user is typing, the code that they're typing is probably not valid, which might throw the parser off and result in bad autocomplete suggestions. As I said, it's a lot of work to do this right.

That said, if syntax highlighting is all you need, you can probably use an editor that already has it. Depending on the technology you're using, you might be able to make use [Scintilla](https://www.scintilla.org/) or [AvalonEdit](https://github.com/icsharpcode/AvalonEdit). You won't get intellisense (autocomplete) or error highlighting or any other features that depend on understanding the meaning of the code (semantic analysis), though, but you might get half-decent syntax highlighting.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, things got much clearer now.

Only a couple more questions. The editor i am developing is in C# WPF, so AvalonEdit seems like the perfect choice. If you are familiar with it, any thoughts on it about performance, does it implement this compiler theory etc.?

Comment: Yep, AvalonEdit is a really good choice if you're in .NET. It has support for syntax highlighting for ~20 languages. The syntax highlighting is based on regular expressions, so it's rather basic. It does not understand anything about the user's code, so it will not give you autocomplete, error squiggles, symbol tool-tips etc., you'd have to have a separate library/ies to parse the user's code so you can offer meaningful autocomplete, error highlighting etc...

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. But what would a complex syntax highlighter mean if the regex method is rather basic? I imagine it's still a very good solution, especially if you expand on it, but still out of curiosity.

Comment: A complex syntax highlighter will never be coded in Regex. it would use a compiler frontend : Lexer and Parser to determine symbols etc. At this point you can then expand and add Type tooltips, squiggles etc